# Why would a post-apocalyptic group would want to rebuild the USA long after USA falls (i.e. not for continuity of government)?

Tags: government, post-apocalypse

Out in the East Coast Wastes, in between Virginia and Maryland territory, is a deep crater, that was once known as DC. It was hit multiple times during the war, and most of the  structures collapsed, and became piles of rubble and debris. The few people who where able to survive fled from DC, as the radiation was at insane levels. The radiations long gone now, but few go their now, as local legends tell that that 68 mile stretch of land is cursed. No one journeyed their. Not until the Founding Fathers Tribe.

The Founding Fathers Tribe, whose original name was lost to history, moved into the DC area around the late 25th century. They built a little statue out of some rubble, and claimed that they were the successors of the original Union. The new USA. They only had 70 miles of space, and a population of around 1000 citizens. But, they do have a government, that is a, twisted, version of the US government. They have a president, who acts more like a tribal chief, and a cabinet of only four, not including the president. The Defense minister, Agricultural minister, a presidential adviser, and a messenger and jester. Their is just one thing I can’t think of.

What would be a plausible reason for why the Founding Fathers Tribe would want to rebuild the USA?

***Criteria***

So, the Washington DC area is full of many dangerous creatures since the absence of humans has let them flourish, so whatever reason you put must be capable of getting the average person willing to risk their own safety.

Comment: After empires fall, there are always people who want to restore them in their former glory.

Comment: @Alexander: But, the USA isn’t an empire? What do you mean

Comment: Sorry for being a bit poetic here, the correct definition can be "large and historically successful countries".

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't an empire"?! It is as big as empires ever got, and more influential than any other empire in history.

Comment: @Alexander: Oh, I get you. Sorta like the “South will rise again” type thing

Comment: Please add objective criteria to judge answers better or worse. VtC opinion based for now.

Comment: @DTCooper Not just that... the USA has military stationed all over the planet. We have territories that are not states. We dictate the conditions other nations live under. We even have a Pax Americana analogous to the Pax Romana ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Americana ). We are an empire.

Comment: Why there were 3 major political entities claiming to be successors of Rome ("Eastern Roman Empire" aka "Byzantine Empire", "Holy Roman Empire" sometimes jokingly referred to as "Nor Holy, Not Roman and Not an Empire" and "Russia" aka. "We never had anything to do with Rome whatsoever, we don't even use same alphabet but we are totally the Third Rome"), out of which only one (Byzantines) were contemporary of Rome? Many reasons, prestige of potentially being new Roman Emperor just one among them.

Comment: And to chip in on "empire". USA is an empire in every aspect but name (most likely purely because of PR reasons). From size and influence, to method of wealth acquisition by stealing, pardon, "trading" it out of tributaries and colonies, pardon, "trade partners". Any political entity that is unable to stand up to USA (most of the world, easier to count who can stand up to USA: China, EU, Japan and Russia) ends up forced into trade deals that benefit one side. Just like British and Roman Empires, merely with modern ways of exploiting the weak.

Comment: You might ask why the US Constitution drew so heavily on the Roman Republic.

Comment: Please review [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened).

Comment: Following from Miech, so did the Nazis (Third Reich) and Napoleon. Why create a new narrative when you can co-opt an existing one and the goodwill(?) that comes with it.  Think of it as knock-off goods of an existing, well-known brand. That said, thinking of reasons why people do X to move the story along is the author's job, not people on the internet; you decide why people do X, we can only advise whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be a plausible reason for why the Founding Fathers Tribe would want to rebuild the USA?

They think that the USA was a nice place, and they want to make something just as nice.

There is plenty of examples in literature. My favorite ones are all concentrated in one single videogame - Fallout: New Vegas. In this game, there are some tribes that wish to emulate, or even surpass, past civilizations in terms of greatness:

- Caesar's Legion is a group of people who cosplay as legionaires - think roman centurions carrying laser rifles. They have a very poor and limited grasp of latin but try to shove it into their day-to-day communication anyway, from salutes to how they name themselves. They implemented a currency based on coins with the face of Caesar in it. They do it for no other reason than thinking that ancient rome was the epithome of cool. The fact their slave population will rebel here and there does not seem to bother them, and the doctrine of trying to annex neighbours through war has made it really hard for them to make friends, but still...
- The New California Republic is kinda trying to rebuild California. All the way to the flag, though now it has a two-headed bear in it (because radiation). They try hard to look like the good guys because, you know, freedom and democracy (the Legion also claims this about themselves). At the end of the day they are suffocating people with inept leadership and anacronisms, while thinking they are the bastion of all that is good.
- The Khans want to become the mongols of the 23rd century. They don't know fertilizant about who Ghenghis Khan was other than knowing that A) he went to wars and B) his helmet had horns. But hey, rule of cool, right?
- The Kings are the only ones who are even close to going the right direction towards good and enlightment. In the ruins of Las Vegas they found buildings and memorabilia dedicated to a man who was called "The King" in his own time. They don't know much about Elvis Presley - they don't even know his true name - but the leader of the Kings concluded that if so many people worshipped the man, then he was some kind of holy person in his own time, and by having his tribe emulate Elvis the world become a better place. Yes, this is a cargo cult that seems to have come out of a certain Mojo Nixon song.

What all the tribes above have in common is a very limited knowledge of the past, oftern fragmented and distorted. But the knowledge they have places whatever they are trying to emulate as the best thing ever. In some cases we, from the real 21st century, might be complied to agree based on our own biases. In most cases, though, such adoration of "a time that was better than now" defies logic and disencourages further research.

---

Back to your guys. One thousand individuals are not enough to rebuild the whole of what makes the United States of America. What era from the US are they trying to reenact? The 1800's? The 20's? The 70's?

Also notice that, unlike the majority of countries in the world, the US are huge. It's a continent-sized country with more than a couple hundred million people in it. There are many cultures, and cultures within cultures across the states. Not seldomly their ideals clash due to their antagonistic schools of thought. One thousand people are probably not enough to represent them all. Are they really going to cover all cultural groups that make America? The yuppies, baby boomers, generation Y, generation Z, millenials, hipsters, hill billies, WASP's, B-boys, hippies, emos, jenova witnesses, dreamers, flat earthers, vegans, alt-righters, antifas, militant atheists, soccer moms, metalheads...  And these are just a few. Are all of them going to be represented in the new, 26th century USA? I think not.

Those people probably saw a very limited snapshot of a small group of americans from a short span of time and concluded that the ideals of those people from the past matched their own tribe's ideals. Then they performed the following silogism:

- USA was great;
- Those few people from the past that we identify with lived in the USA;
- Therefore, if we emulate that very limited sample of people from the past, our new country will be as great as the USA were.

Which makes for a cargo cult at best. Whether this idea succeeds into doing a future nation that thrives, though, is up to your writing.

Comment: Their are 1000 people, not 100. But, most of them, actually almost all of them, are patriotic about their 70 mile tiny country

Comment: @DTCooper I adjusted the number in the answer, but I think the point works just the same whether we are talking about 100, 1,000 or maybe even 10,000 people.

Comment: Yeah, but I did not plan for them to have that much variety in culture anyway

Answer (score 7):

Nigh three thousand years ago, there was a kingdom called Israel. Under King David and King Solomon and their descendants, it prospered. For a while. In 587 BCE, what remained of the kingdom, by then less than half of it, got conquered by Babylon, the Temple sacked, the people exiled.

But the people didn't want to give up on their land, and when Cyrus the Great allowed their return, they went back to Jerusalem, and in 521 BCE started construction of the Second Temple. The Kingdom of Judea lasted for a while, until in 70 CE Rome sacked the Temple and exiled the people.

But the people again didn't want to give up on their land. For two thousand years, the Grace over bread included a prayer for Jerusalem. Each wedding included an oath to remember Jerusalem. On Holidays it was said "next year in Jerusalem". Prayers were towards Jerusalem. And when it became possible, they came back to this land of malaria-infested swamps, desert and hostile neighbours, and founded the State of Israel.

Why on earth? Because Jerusalem is the heart of the Jewish identity. To forsake Jerusalem was to forsake who we are, take an axe to our own roots. Deeper than history, deeper than faith, deeper than love.

**Imagine your Founding Fathers Tribe feeling about the USA the way Jews feel about Jerusalem** - as the keystone of their group identity. Imagine them "weeping on the rivers of Babylon" - not only missing the beautiful past, but building their philosophy, values, art, etc. around the USA history, and what the USA aspired to be. Israel was founded by people willing to forsake everything and give up their very lives for the dream of Jerusalem. So would your new USA.

Comment: So they’ll be weeping on the rivers of Potomac

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a little like a [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) government to me. The people who occupy the ruins find references to the previous government, one of surpassing power and reach. They figure anyone who could raise such a mighty government in such dismal land (DC is, basically, built on a swamp) must have had a superlative governing structure.

At its less cultish, they basically conclude from the available evidence that the US government is the perfect form of a republic (more fools they, then) and seek to emulate its particulars. With this approach, they probably care more about the *structure* (e.g. a strong executive, a Cabinet of advisors, a bicameral legislature) than things like titles.

At its more cultish, they attach totemic importance to the names and concepts of the US government, probably with an imperfect understanding of them. They may conclude that mimicking these titles will grant them power, or it might be a form of ancestor worship. They're more likely to do things like slavishly copy ideas out of books, or have bizarre appendices that don't do anything. ("Congratulations, Bob, you're my new Secretary of Energy." "But Mr. President, what does the Secretary of Energy do?" "I don't know, but we have to have one.")

You could also have something in the middle where different groups of people have different opinions of the old government, with some seeking to emulate its form and others its iconography, and derive political or other conflict from the different groups.

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest Destiny**

From coast to coast american artifacts have been found, this way they lay claim to them all and the land.

If they know any lore of the US they will know that is wasn't a single thing, but built by large sub-units that made a huge alliance. If they plan to conquer the world it is much less hassle to do it in big bites than sack every city.

**It is easier than the alternatives**

Animals are aways less dangerous than people. They had to leave wherever they came from, probably at a run. By inserting themselves into a powerful myth they save dignity, by taking land no one else wants they avoid conflict.

Comment: interesting points about saving dignity by inserting themselves into myth and taking land no one else wants to avoid conflict

Answer (score 0):

They found some history.

Theres been a lot of colonies, and just about every single one is a third world nation now. The USA went from colony to leading world power in around 100 years. Anyone convinced that it wasnt the USA regime responsible (directly or indirectly) for thr DC crater with that knowledge would want to tey and restore that and hope to have the same mindblowing success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you the cynical perspective. They don't want to restore the USA that was. You've already said their governing practices are a twisted version of what was. It doesn't sound like they care very much about what the USA was. From a cynical perspective, I'd say they care about power. They want their tribe to rule, and what better way to legitimize their rule than to claim that they are the rightful successors to the previous government? Settling in the DC crater gives them access to a large number of artifacts that legitimize them. Their President has decorated his living quarters with artifacts from the white house, and their places of meeting are likewise decorated with relics of the past. They use these symbols to stir nostalgia for what was in the other people they meet. They conjure dreams of past greatness, and make promises of similar greatness in the future. All of this draws in other tribes who remember, or have at least heard stories, of the USA that was. Some of these tribes declare allegiance to the Founding Fathers tribe. Some that don't join will at least respect them.

I've written as a cynic, but it's possible that the Founding Fathers Tribe buys into their own story. Perhaps they first went to DC to hold an election and "fairly" determine who should rule the nation. Maybe they are lead by a descendant of the last President, or at least of someone in the [line of succession.](http://www.ushistory.org/gov/7c.asp) They don't have to be deceptive - they might really believe what they're selling.